# Echarts -> stacking independent bars

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm working with echarts and trying to stack bars that have independent data. Basically, it should look something like this (just horizontal instead of vertical):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKf5a.png
(taken from [Pandas- stacked bar chart with independent/unrelated partitions of bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824636/pandas-stacked-bar-chart-with-independent-unrelated-partitions-of-bars))

So far my code is (use in https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html):

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value',

    },

    tooltip: 'show',

        yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data : ["Name 1","Name 2"],
    },

        series: [
        {
        data: [210],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '2',
        },
        {
        data: [20],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '2',
        },
                {
                    name: 'City Beta',
        data: [75],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '4',
        },
        {
            name: 'City Alpha',
        data: [25],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '4',
        }
    ]
};
```

I need to name every bar independently. Is this possible? Ideally it could look like this: 
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack

But with every bar having independent values, names etc. None of the values and names will repeat.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Sure You can...

Using this below code you can get it.

```
label: {
normal: {
    show: true,
    position: 'insideRight'
}
```

},

Sample Code:

```
var option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'value',

},

tooltip: 'show',

yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ["Name 1", "Name 2"],
},

series: [{
        data: [210],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '2',
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'insideRight'
            }
        },
    },
    {
        data: [20],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '2',
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'insideRight'
            }
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'City Beta',
        data: [75],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '4',
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'insideRight'
            }
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'City Alpha',
        data: [25],
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '4',
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'insideRight'
            }
        },
    }
]
```

};

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: in this case ,"Name2" is unuseable,

Comment: What do you mean unusable? I can't get you.